# Excel: Use VBA to remove first two characters of string if they are a number followed by a dash

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel values where some strings start with a number followed by a dash 6-. I need to remove the number and dash for all strings that start like this. Using VBA because I already have a macro that is removing other unwanted characters.

Comment: If you show us the code you've tried and where its failing, we can help you better. Not many are willing to write code for free, especially since it will be part of a larger, already existing code base. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more on getting the most effective help here.

Comment: Well to clarify my "code base" is currently one line. I'm a complete noob to Excel but I'm trying. And regarding "writing code for free", also just one line and this forum is full of one liners for free.

Comment: If the macro you already have that is removing other unwanted characters is just one line, then post it. We'll be able to help you better. It'll save a lot of potential back and forth and questions from you in case any solution provided doesn't integrate easily with your existing code..

Comment: Try putting together the [Left function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251556.aspx), the [Like operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251796.aspx) and the [Mid function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251677.aspx) and report back if you get stuck